# If statement using lapply to scrape multiple urls with different nodes/tags

Tags: r, if-statement, web-scraping

I want to scrape the titles of multiples urls. Depending on the website page, the titles are under different tags/nodes. I would like to use an if statement so if I get character (0) using one of the nodes it should then use the other tag/node and so on.

## These are the three different nodes the code can find within all the urls I want to scrape

```
(".tittleArticuloOpinion")
(".nameColumnista") 
(".article-header h2")
```

## I've tried this code and I get chr(0) for each website

```
prueba_titulos2 =lapply(noticias_semana_lapply[12:14,1], function(x) {
  tryCatch(
    {
       Sys.sleep(0.1)
  read_html(x) %>% html_nodes(".tittleArticuloOpinion") %>%  html_text %>% 
  {if(length(.) == 0) read_html(x) %>% html_nodes(".nameColumnista") %>% html_text else {
  if (length(.) == 0) read_html(x) %>% html_nodes(".article-header h2") %>% 
  html_text}} %>% as.character
  },
  error = function(cond) return(NULL),
  finally = print(x)
  )
})
```

`noticias_semana_lapply` is a list of 10.000 urls. Here is a reproducible example of the three websites I am scraping:

```
dput(noticias_semana_lapply[12:14,1])
"http://www.semana.com/nacion/articulo/cuales-cree-temas-principales-deben-tratar-dialogos-del-gobierno-farc/263693-3"
"http://www.semana.com/confidenciales-semanacom/articulo/las-farc-marcha-patriotica/263691-3"
"http://www.semana.com/nacion/articulo/procuraduria-formulo-cargos-contra-dos-excongresistas-chocoanos/263685-3"
```

## I've also tried this and get NULL for the three links

```
prueba_titulos3 =lapply(noticias_semana_lapply[12:14,1], function(x) {
  tryCatch(
    {
      Sys.sleep(0.1)
      if(character(length = 0)) {
      read_html(x) %>% html_nodes(".tittleArticuloOpinion") %>% html_text
      read_html(x) %>% html_nodes(".nameColumnista") %>% html_text 
      read_html(x) %>% html_nodes(".article-header h2") %>% html_text 
      } else {.}%>%
        as.character
    },
    error = function(cond) return(NULL),
    finally = print(x)
  )
})
```

Could someone please help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Difficult to help without reproducible example. Can you add `dput(noticias_semana_lapply[12:14,1])` ?

Comment: Hi, @Ronak Shah. I edited the post. Would be that enough? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I noticed that all the URL's you have shared have length greater than 0 so it doesn't really go into the second loop. What do you expect the output to be when `length(.) != 0)` ?

Comment: I think I made a mistake. I need to scrape those three nodes from the websites. So if one of the nodes return character (0), then it should try the next node and so on. So at the end I can collect all the titles from each link (no matter they have different nodes/tags). Perhaps instead of length I should use character?  Could you please guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is you should not use `if...else` but only `if` since using the former would not check for next condition if the first condition is not satisfied. Here is an easy to read version which returns output for all 3 of the links shared.

```
library(rvest)

lapply(noticias_semana_lapply[12:14,1], function(x) {
     new_x <- read_html(x) %>% html_nodes(".tittleArticuloOpinion") %>% html_text
     if(length(new_x) == 0) 
        new_x <- read_html(x) %>% html_nodes(".nameColumnista") %>% html_text
     if(length(new_x) == 0) 
        new_x <- read_html(x) %>% html_nodes(".article-header h2") %>% html_text
     return(new_x)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it not sufficient to use CSS Or syntax to match on any of those?

i.e.

```
read_html(url) %>% html_nodes(".tittleArticuloOpinion, .nameColumnista, .article-header h2") %>% html_text
```

Example:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

urls = c("http://www.semana.com/nacion/articulo/cuales-cree-temas-principales-deben-tratar-dialogos-del-gobierno-farc/263693-3"
         ,"http://www.semana.com/confidenciales-semanacom/articulo/las-farc-marcha-patriotica/263691-3"
         ,"http://www.semana.com/nacion/articulo/procuraduria-formulo-cargos-contra-dos-excongresistas-chocoanos/263685-3")

for(url in urls){
  x <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes(".tittleArticuloOpinion, .nameColumnista, .article-header h2") %>% html_text
  print(x)
 }
```

Comment: It could. However, since I am scraping 10.000 articles and I had already written the code using `lapply`, I think Ronak Shah suggestion is a bit more useful in this case. Thanks!

Comment: I tested your code since it is much cleaner. However, it is giving me just the result of the last url (not the title for each link). What could be the problem? Because it prints the title of each url but  `x` just saves the result of the last one.

Comment: It only saves the last one because I am overwriting in loop. It was merely for demonstrative purposes. You can apply a function and inside that function have  the Or applied e.g. function(x) {new_x <- read_html(x) %>% html_nodes(".tittleArticuloOpinion, .nameColumnista, .article-header h2") %>% html_text}   - similar construct to your existing.

Comment: I applied the function following your suggestion and it worked! I did not know I could use multiple tags in the same `html_nodes`. Thanks a lot!